# Locking rows with unique index

Tags: postgresql, transactions, locking

I have a concurrent workflow which inserts a record with a unique index on column `A` and column `B`, and if this is successful, performs an async action that cannot be rolled back (API request), inside a single transaction.

Said API request should only ever happens once, but currently it's possibly that it gets triggered multiple times if that record is being inserted in parallel.

If i'm not mistaken, the way to solve this problem is to set a lock on the offending row to make sure that any parallel inerts will wait until the initial transaction is complete.

Which lock would be the correct one for this usecase?

Answer (score 0):

No need for an explicit lock.

If a second transactions inserts the **same** values for the PK that an un-committed other transaction has already inserted, the second will wait until the first transactions commits or rolls back.

If the first transaction rolls back, the second will succeed. If the first transaction commits, the second will get an "unique key violation" error.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I perform the API request inside the transaction, so two transactions could insert the row, send the request, and then one of them will rollback.

The API request is inside the transaction because if the API requests fails, the inserts should be rolled back.